# offset lexis grid by one

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset that has age cohorts from 0 - 80, and years 1900-2021. I am making a lexis plot with this data using the lexis_grid function from the [LexisPlotR package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=LexisPlotR). I am using the following code to get started:

```
library(LexisPlotR)

lexis_grid(year_start = 1900, 
           year_end = 2021, 
           age_start = 0,
           age_end = 80,
           delta = 10
)
```

However, what this does is sets the upper righthand end of the diaganal lines at 2021, and so they don't like up with vertical decade lines and it just looks wrong:

[image]

Any advice on how to index the diagonal lines to start at 1900, rather than end at 2021?

Comment: Change year_end to 2020 or 2030? it has to increment in 10s?

Comment: Yep, that one I should of figured. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Change *year_end* to 2020 or 2030, so it increments in 10s to match with age increment - *delta*:

```
lexis_grid(year_start = 1900, 
           year_end = 2030, 
           age_start = 0,
           age_end = 80,
           delta = 10)
```

[image]